# query to check detail from table if found then yes else NO

Tags: mysql

Below is my query. This is working properly problem is that from like table I am not able to check whether particular user is liking the element on not. if person likes show  yes, if doesn't then show no.

```
SELECT
      u_m.*,concat(usr.fname,' ',usr.lname) as NAME,
      u_m_u.sent_to,u_m_u.sent_by,u_m_u.shared_of,
      u_m_u.author,u_m_u.adddate

FROM user_message_users AS u_m_u
      LEFT JOIN user_messages AS u_m
        ON u_m.messageid = u_m_u.messageid
       LEFT JOIN smsusers AS usr
        ON u_m_u.sent_by=usr.id
       LEFT JOIN likes 
        ON u_m.messageid=likes.element_id 
        and
        likes.liked_by='1'
        group by u_m_u.messageid,u_m_u.sent_to
       ORDER BY u_m_u.adddate desc;
```

Like table is

```
create table likes(
element_id varchar(100),
element_type varchar(100),
liked_by varchar(100), 
foreign key(liked_by) references smsusers(id)
 ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
adddate timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
primary key(element_id,liked_by));
```

My query [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4b87/11) is

Comment: Please check the query.

Comment: What is problem with this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query :-

```
SELECT
      u_m.*,concat(usr.fname,' ',usr.lname) as NAME,
      u_m_u.sent_to,u_m_u.sent_by,u_m_u.shared_of,
      u_m_u.author,u_m_u.adddate,if(likes.liked_by is null,'No','Yes')
as likees

FROM user_message_users AS u_m_u
      LEFT JOIN user_messages AS u_m
        ON u_m.messageid = u_m_u.messageid
       LEFT JOIN smsusers AS usr
        ON u_m_u.sent_by=usr.id
       LEFT JOIN likes 
        ON u_m.messageid=likes.element_id 
and
likes.liked_by='1'
group by u_m_u.messageid,u_m_u.sent_to
ORDER BY u_m_u.adddate desc;
```

Try [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4b87/22)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      u_m.*,concat(usr.fname,' ',usr.lname) as NAME,
      u_m_u.sent_to,u_m_u.sent_by,u_m_u.shared_of,
      u_m_u.author,u_m_u.adddate,
      if (likes.element_id IS NULL, "No", "Yes") Likes
```